# Select rows from 6 am to 6 am

Tags: mysql

Help create a query that will select records from the table for the past period from 6AM until 6AM, the table has a timestamp field.
I will explain, for example:

```
Now: 2019-06-15 04:44:42
Period: 2019-06-13 06:00:00 - 2019-06-14 06:00:00

Now: 2019-06-15 07:44:42
Period: 2019-06-14 06:00:00 - 2019-06-15 06:00:00

Now: 2019-06-16 01:44:42
Period: 2019-06-14 06:00:00 - 2019-06-15 06:00:00
```

I think I was not the easiest request:

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `timestamp`
    BETWEEN
        DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL '1 6' DAY_HOUR), INTERVAL 6 HOUR)
    AND
        DATE_ADD(DATE(NOW() - INTERVAL '0 6' DAY_HOUR), INTERVAL 6 HOUR);
```

How simpler?

Comment: Note an edge case: `2019-01-01 05:00:00` what would you expect?

Comment: We need the last finished period from 6 am to 6 am. For 2019-01-01 05:00:00 this period: 2018-12-30 06:00:00 - 2018-12-31 06:00:00

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the upper range limit with:

```
date(now() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR
```

The lower limit would be exactly one day (24 hours) earlier:

```
date(now() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR - INTERVAL 1 day
```

So your query could be:

```
SELECT *
FROM `table` t
WHERE t.timestamp >= date(now() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR - INTERVAL 1 day
  AND t.timestamp <  date(now() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR
```

But to avoid code duplication I would rewrite it to:

```
SELECT t.*
FROM `table` t
CROSS JOIN (
    SELECT date(now() - INTERVAL 6 HOUR) + INTERVAL 6 HOUR as upper_limit
) r -- r for "range"
WHERE t.timestamp >= r.upper_limit - INTERVAL 1 day
  AND t.timestamp <  r.upper_limit
```

You can though use `<= r.upper_limit` instead of `< r.upper_limit` to get the same result as with `BETWEEN`.

Comment: This is how I would do it. +10  (I would opt to put the join condition into an `ON` clause and omit the `CROSS` keyword.)

Comment: @spencer7593 Tanks. `JOIN (..) r ON ..` is of course an option - and would save 9 bytes of code ;-). But for me a CROSS JOIN like that is just a way to define a "constant", which can be reused multiple time in any clause. The same way as using `SET @upper_limit = ...` - But avoiding a second query. Anyway I'd be fine with both.

Comment: works either way. I typically include the (entirely optional) `CROSS` keyword when there is no join condition, mostly as a reminder to me (and an aid to the future reader), that the absence of a join condition was intentional and not an oversight. And in this case, there is a join condition between `t` and `r`... but this all just about a personal preference, ... i can also see the point of using the CROSS keyword since we have a guarantee that `r` is returning exactly one row. Omitting CROSS and replacing WHERE with ON is just style, and doesn't change the query.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT start, start +interval 24 hour end
  FROM ( SELECT date(now()) 
                - interval if(hour(now())>6, 1, 2) day 
                + interval 6 hour 
                as start
       ) dates;
```